# How Can I smooth out the Values of Mouse X in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, smoothing

I am trying to create a script that tilts the cam on the Z axis dynamic so that when you look to the right the camera tilts sideways like it is getting pulled but somehow my cam just jitters and I know why but I dont't know how to fix hit. The Reason is the value of the Mouse X axis. When I am printing it out I can see that ervy second value of it is 0 and the other ones are the real value so my camera snaps from 0 to the rotion I want.

The first part in the lateUbdate Function is just for the First person controll of the cam

```
    public float MausEmpfindlichkeit;
    float CamTilt;

    //transform
    public Transform PlayerBody;


    //floats
    float Xrot = 0f;


    //Scripte
    public RotaionSpeed PlayerSpeed;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        TurnCamToSpeed();

        float MausX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * Time.deltaTime * MausEmpfindlichkeit;
        float MausY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * Time.deltaTime * MausEmpfindlichkeit;

        Xrot -= MausY;

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(Xrot, 0f, CamTilt);
        PlayerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * MausX);

        print(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"));

    }

    void TurnCamToSpeed()
    {
        float CamTiltValaue = Random.Range(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X"));
        CamTilt = -CamTiltValaue * 3;
        
    }
```

My question is, how do I prevent that from happening and have a smooth Value of The Mouse X axis

[This is the current behaviour but it is hard so because of the low fps rate of the gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNOM3.gif)

Answer (score 0):

In general note that [`GetAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) in contrary to [`GetAxisRaw`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxisRaw.html) already **is smoothed** a little.

But instead of hard setting

```
CamTilt = -CamTiltValaue * 3;
```

you could add some more smoothing using [`Mathf.Lerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html) like e.g.

```
CamTilt = Mathf.Lerp(CamTilt, -CamTiltValaue * 3, someFactor * Time.deltaTime);
```

where `someFactor` multiplied by `Time.deltaTime` should be somewhere between `0` and `1` so you have to play a bit with it.

Still note though that this might result in something barely moving as you chose a new value every frame which might end up more or less fixed in the middle.